# CSS not displaying when i run locahost

Tags: php, css, html, ubuntu-14.04

am using Ubuntu OS and when i run my site in browser as an HTML file it displays the CSS but when i convert the site to a PHP file and run it using local host it doesn't display my CSS.i have attached some screenshots of the HTML and PHP views of the navigation bar.thank you for your time[HTML file view in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncRIE.png)

[PHP file view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fe2p5.png)

Comment: Did you install apache and PHP through apt or did you use a third party package like xampp?

Comment: right click and view source, click the css, did you receive an error?

Comment: @Pazuzu156 i used apt

Comment: @ColourDalnet i didnt get what you meant please repeat more clearly

Comment: http://prntscr.com/l0f8se

Comment: @ColourDalnet when i view page source it displays my source code

Comment: are you using css file using file *.css or write the css directly in header? better provie your actual code instead showing us the resulted images.

Comment: Glad the answer worked for you. The problem with installing through apt is you do have to do some manual configuration. Xampp does all that for you if you need a quick test server. Lastly, as you mentioned permissions also play a part. If you don't have read access, nothing can be displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First check your css file. Is it available or not.
- If that file is available then check the file directly wether you have access or not. For example, if the file in css directory. Try access it directly by url. Do you get any error?
- If you doesn't have access to directory probably htaccess configuration or directory issue (set the directory access to public or chmod 777) and try to give htaccess to allow all https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

> ```
> Order allow,
> deny Allow from all
> ```

Comment: thanks.all i did was to change the permissions of the folder that the CSS file was in by going to /var directory in terminal and inputting chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/foldername

Comment: Glad it helps :)

Answer (score -5):

$style ='';

```
            $style .='.'.$element_class.' .team-intro h5{color: '.$membar_info_color.';}';
            $style .='.'.$element_class.' .team-intro span{color: '.$membar_info_color.';}';
            $style .='.'.$element_class.' .team-intro {background: '.$membar_info_bg.';}';
            $style .='.'.$element_class.' .team-hover {background: '.$overlay_bg.';}';

            $style .='.'.$element_class.' .desk, .desk h4, p, .team-hover .s-link a {color: '.$desc_color.'; box-shadow:none;}';
            $style .='.'.$element_class.' .desk, .desk h4, p, .team-hover .s-link a:hover {color: '.$hover_color.';}';

            echo $border;

            if (empty($border)) {
                $style .= '.'.$element_class.' .team-hover {border: 20px solid '.$border_color.';}';
            }else{
                $style .= '.'.$element_class.' .team-hover {}';
            }

            $style .= '</style>';


        $output = '';
        $output .= $style;
        $output .= '<div class="team-member '.$element_class.' '.$element_id.'">
               HTML Code.....
            </div>';
        return $output;
```

Please try same way i hope you solved your problem. Thanks.

Comment: That's..not helpful

Comment: my source code has no errors,because as an HTML file it works well,i think the issue is connected to apache2 because its the service am using to run local host

Comment: Can i see your code please

Comment: so sorry i cant give you my source code.never the less it doesn't have any error.i found a solution to the problem. Thank you for your help